# Different directory for bash_completion (auto-complete subfolders under specified directory)

Tags: bash-completion

To be able to enter `dev my-[tab]` anywhere on my system and receive auto completion like

```
$ dev my-[tab]
my-project
my-awesome-project
```

I created a file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/` with the following content:

```
_dev()
{
    PROJECTS=$(ls /development)
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${PROJECTS}" -- $cur) )
}

complete -F _dev dev
```

This works just fine, but I would also like to be able to auto-complete subfolders:

```
[~] $ dev my-p[tab]
[~] $ dev my-project/[tab][tab]
src    doc
[~] $ dev my-project/s[tab][enter]
[/development/my-project/src] $
```

So basically, I would like to have auto-completion for `dev` the same way it is for `cd`.

`dev` is only an alias:

```
alias dev='gotodev'
gotodev ()
{ 
    cd /development/$1
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrote an example:

```
[/tmp] # cat compspec
g_proj_dir=/tmp/projects

dev()
{
    cd $g_proj_dir/$1
}

_dev()
{
    local cmd=$1 cur=$2 pre=$3
    local _cur compreply

    _cur=$g_proj_dir/$cur
    compreply=( $( compgen -d "$_cur" ) )
    COMPREPLY=( ${compreply[@]#$g_proj_dir/} )
    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        COMPREPLY[0]=${COMPREPLY[0]}/
    fi
}

complete -F _dev -o nospace dev
[/tmp] # source ./compspec
[/tmp] #
[/tmp] # cd /tmp/
[/tmp] # mkdir -p projects/{bar,foo}{1,2}/mod{1,2}/submod{1,2}
[/tmp] # touch    projects/{bar,foo}{1,2}/mod{1,2}/submod{1,2}/file{1,2}
[/tmp] # dev <TAB><TAB>
bar1  bar2  foo1  foo2
[/tmp] # dev f<TAB>
[/tmp] # dev foo
[/tmp] # dev foo<TAB><TAB>
foo1  foo2
[/tmp] # dev foo2<TAB>
[/tmp] # dev foo2/
[/tmp] # dev foo2/<TAB>
[/tmp] # dev foo2/mod
[/tmp] # dev foo2/mod<TAB><TAB>
foo2/mod1  foo2/mod2
[/tmp] # dev foo2/mod2<TAB>
[/tmp] # dev foo2/mod2/
... ...
```

Comment: if you want to show only last directory instead of full path in the suggestions you can add the following option: 'compopt -o filenames' in the '_dev()' function.
Souce: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19752622/2450748

Comment: @nexayq, or just `complete -o filenames ...`? i did not get point of putting it in the func.

Comment: you are right, both approaches achieve the same result. more users will probably prefer to add an option in the command as you mentioned.