# bash complete path in function with parameters

Tags: bash, function, alias, completion

I want to write a small alias aka function to open up vim sessions fast.

```
vims () {
  vim -S "${HOME}/Sessions/${1}"
}
```

How can I make bash complete/suggest the session files in the path, when entering `vims`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

Based on pynexj [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737675/different-directory-for-bash-completion) and my daily use:

```
_autocomplete()
{
    local cmd=$1 cur=$2 pre=$3 from_path=$4
    local _cur compreply

    _cur=$from_path/$cur
    compreply=( $( compgen -d "$_cur" ) )
    COMPREPLY=( ${compreply[@]#$from_path/} )
    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        COMPREPLY[0]=${COMPREPLY[0]}/
    fi
}

vims()
{
    vim -S ~/Sessions/$1
}

_vims_autocomplete()
{
    _autocomplete "$1" "$2" "$3" ~/Sessions
}

complete -F _vims_autocomplete -o nospace vims

# This way allow me to create different alias using the same autocomplete

gogit()
{
    cd ~/git/$1
}

_gogit_autocomplete()
{
    _autocomplete "$1" "$2" "$3" ~/git
}

complete -F _gogit_autocomplete -o nospace gogit
```

You can get more information about complete [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) and a tutorial [here](https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial.html).